# Cycles rendering output different from shown while processing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

i'm rendering an image with a vehicle on it, and it seems to get pixelated on the final output of the render itself, when it's processing it looks great and is working but when it ends the image looks pixelated.
This only happens to that shader of all the objects on the scene, and is from a linked collection (2.8) from another file.

The sampling on the render is 1000 and the image has a resolution of 1920x1080, but this object is a little part of the whole screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you delete everything else except the effected geometry and shader and attach the .blend file to your question? You can attach .blend files on Blender Stack Exchange using this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: But the geometry with the problem is a link from a collection, should i upload the two files? The original file doest not give this problem.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if it's possible for you to share it without sharing your assets that you might not want to share publicly. The problem does not seem very straight forward. ...at least to me. People might figure it out a lot quicker with the possibility to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MartinZ Thank you, i was able to upload to WeTransfer due to the file size, hope you can find what's going on with the cabin shader because i'm strill trying options (like even re-creating the geometry, new materials, etc) and it doesnt seem to work https://we.tl/t-mnuBdJyP7A